# Excel: Sum columns, multiply with column and sum rows

Tags: excel, sumproduct

we are using excel to do our capacity planning in the team. We have a bunch of people (P1-P3) that fill in a table. For each day they put if they work the entire day (1), work half-day (0.5) or are off (0). Some people have additional responsibilities and are not working 100% on our project. The percentage how much they work for are project is set in the %Work cell (0-1).

I'm looking for a way to calculate the total available capacity per week: For each week (mon-fri), for each person sum up the capacity for that week, multiply it with their %Work, then accumulate this over all people.

My initial approach was to create a hidden column for each week in which I sum up the raw capacity for each person, then use the sumproduct to multiply this cell with the %work and sum it up over all people. However, people kept mass deleting columns when they changed their plan, deleting the hidden columns as well.

Is there a way to do something like sumproduct in one step, but instead of choosing two columns, I choose one column and the sum of other columns: %Work * (M+T+W+T+F)

**Example** from the picture: P1 has 5 full "raw" working days in week 1, P2 has 4.5 "raw" days and P3 4 "raw" days. I want to multiply the 5 days with the 1 of P1 (=5 effective days), the 4.5 with 1 (=4.5 effective days) and the 4 with 0.5 (=2 effective days), according to the %Work column, add then sum up to a total of 11.5.

excel: Microsoft apps 365 for enterprise / V 2108

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhKhG.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, deal with the real problem and use password protection to allow them to only change values not add / delete columns or calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to multiply the percentage column by the days matrix and add the results up. If you anchor the percentage column, it will be applied to the following week as you copy the formula across:

```
=SUM($C6:$C8*D6:H8)
```

[image]